# Python strange import behavior: import x.y works, from x import y doesn't

Tags: python, importerror

I am having a simple directory structure, like that:

```
MyProject
--main.py
--lib #that's a directory/package
----__init__.py
----view.py
----common_lib.py
----other irrelevant modules...
```

In main.py:

```
from lib import view
```

causes the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name view
```

If instead, I write it like:

```
from lib.view import *
```

This import passes successfully, but next failure happens in view.py, in that:

```
from common_lib import Comments, Locations, ScreenData, ProgressSignal
```

causes:

```
ImportError: No module named 'common_lib'
```

And as it appears from the directory structure, common_lib.py resides in the same directory as view.py, how can it happen that it cannot be found?
How does it come that 'from x import y' doesn't work, and 'from x.y import *' works?
'`__init__.py`' is completely empty BTW. And I am using Python 3.3 32-bit.

What is more annoying, this same program worked 2 days ago.I was testing some code in IDLE and when I thought the code was ready to include in the project, pasted it into PyDev, I was shocked by this error. I changed nothing about my directories or modules.

Also, still more strangeness, running view.py and common_lib.py as standalone (without being imported) runs just fine. It should produce the error if any issues really existed.

Thanks. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `main.py` is still at the top level, you need to use `lib.common_lib`:

```
from lib.common_lib import Comments, Locations, ScreenData, ProgressSignal
```

because the previous line `from lib import view` does not start looking for modules from inside `lib`.

Comment: Thanks. It is really surprising that anything worked for me before. But what do you mean by 'because the previous line...' on to the end?

Comment: If you think in terms of directories or folders, `MyProject` contains `lib` which contains `common_lib`.  If your current location is `MyProject` then the `from` statement can only see the `lib` directory.  The line `from lib import view` does not change your path to start in `lib`, you still have to reference the whole path `lib.common_lib`.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
+--main.py     # from lib import view
+--lib
   +--__init__.py
   +--common_lib.py # Comments, etc.
   +--view.py       # from .common_lib import Comments, etc.
```

This works:

```
from lib import view
```

And this works from `view.py` with a [relative import](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) to indicate `common_lib` is in the same package.

```
from .common_lib import Comments, Locations, ScreenData, ProgressSignal
```

Comment: Thanks for hinting at relative imports. I didn't know such a thing existed.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
danielallan@MacBook:~$mkdir myproject
danielallan@MacBook:~$cd myproject/
danielallan@MacBook:myproject$mkdir lib
danielallan@MacBook:myproject$cd lib
danielallan@MacBook:lib$touch __init__.py
danielallan@MacBook:lib$touch view.py
danielallan@MacBook:lib$touch common_lib.py
danielallan@MacBook:lib$cd ..

In [1]: from lib import view

In [2]: view
Out[2]: <module 'lib.view' from 'lib/view.pyc'>
```

What happens when you try that on your machine? Are you sitting in the wrong directory, or is your path not configured to find these files?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with that project. It just works somewhere else. I have also run the code through IDLE as well as PyDev with no luck. `sys.path` is left at it's defaults. I am not manipulating it in any way.

Comment: By `it` I mean the importing mechanism, not my project working somewhere else.

Comment: I am not on linux/mac. But creating a similar structure on windows works.

Comment: I suggest replacing the blank files your files, one at a time, and seeing when the error shows up.